# JAVA четные елементы массива

Tags: java

Есть массив, из которого хочу вывести все элементы имеющие четный порядковый номер но выводятся все, что не так делаю?

```
 List<String> number_list = con.List();
    for (int i = 0; i < number_list.size(); i++) {
        final String number = number_list.get(i%2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может быть должно быть как-то так?

```
List<String> number_list = con.List();
for (int i = 0; i < number_list.size(); i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) { // Если остаток от деления на 2 равен нулю, значит он чётный
        final String number = number_list.get(i);
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Точно) Спасибо)

Comment: @Drop Если ответ помог - можно ткнуть галочку напротив ответа) Ну и стрелочку)

Comment: даа) там жеж первые 10 мин ограничение. нельзя сразу ответ принять) я выжидал просто) не забыл)

Answer (score 1):

Зачем итерироваться по всем позициям и проверять, является ли позиция чётной? Можно же сразу итерироваться по чётным позициям

```java
for (int i = 0; i < number_list.size(); i += 2) {
    // В этой области видимости только чётные i
}
```

Comment: мне нужно все четные в один массив, все нечетные в другой, так что перебор все равно нужен.А разве += не оператор присваивания? я ведь получу второй элемент массива?

Comment: @Drop *хочу вывести все элементы имеющие четный порядковый номер*. `+=` оператор инкрементирования. `++` увеличивает на 1, `+= n` увеличивает на `n`.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо